# Stripe with PaymentIntents. Following subscription makes new charge

Tags: stripe-payments

I just updated my code to Stripe Payment Intents API and I want to make a subscription to a plan just after the payment.

- When the customer installs the app, a subscription to it is created with a trial period
- When he wants to pay for a longer period, he goes on a page in which he first select the plan he wants, then fill his customer informations (name, mail etc.).
- Then I make a post request to **/payment_intents** with these four informations:

  - amount (Amount of the plan)
  - currency
  - payment_method_type[]
  - customer
- I then send the **client_secret** returned by the request to my js script in order to process the payment.

If the payment succeeds I update the subscription on POST **/subscription/id**
and set **trial_end=now**

But on the Dashboard, I see on my customer page there was two payments:
[image: Customer Payments]

I (think I) know the second charge is made by the subscription, but how can I make a subscription without creating a new charge ?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If the payment succeeds I update the subscription on POST /subscription/id and set trial_end=now

That immediately ends the trial period on the subscription and causes it to immediately try to charge the customer. So that's why you have two charges — one from the payment intent, and one from ending the trial period.

I don't quite understand your flow here though. Usually you would do this in the opposite way :

1. Create the payment intent and process the payment.
2. When that succeeds, *then* create the subscription and set `trial_end=now+30days` (for example, if you are using a 30-day billing period), because the customer has already paid for that upcoming period via the payment intent.

**Update;** to anyone reading this more recently, Billing supports PaymentIntents natively now(each invoice uses a PaymentIntent), so you don't need to use this trial period approach. https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment has the current approach to use!

Comment: Thank you, I didn't really understood the use of trial_end but it's clear now. It solves my problem, thanks!

Comment: @karllekko I have been struggling with this for several days and recently a friend suggested this approach. I had actually been following what that link you posted says to do but the charge always automatically goes through immediately instead of waiting for me to confirm they want to go forward.